# How to use HTML5 Placeholder with Symfony 1.4

Tags: html, symfony1, symfony-1.4, placeholder

I want to set a default message like 'add your comment' to a text input using the html5 placeholder attribute. Somebody know how to do that in Symfony 1.4?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add any html attributes to a widget in the second parameter:

```
$this->form->setWidgets(array(
  'name' => new sfWidgetFormInput(
    array('label'       => 'Your Name'), 
    array('placeholder' => 'Add your comment')
  ),
));
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm very new with SF!

Comment: I don't consider this a realistic solution. It prevents the placeholder attribute from being automatically added to form input's which is really what would be desired instead of manually adding them.